# How to not blocks Azure Web Apps routing names with LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4?

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I have nodejs application hosted in Azure Web Apps. Any URL which contains "LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4" and more are blocked. This IIS specific problem. 
In this article is complete list of limited names

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-shares--directories--files--and-metadata

so example url 
https://myexample.org/api/something/LPT2

IIS returns 404 error code. 
Do you know a way to change configuration of web app to avoid this limitation?

Comment: Would this work? https://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx/

Comment: After I changed configuration my app return 500 error code.